# How To show original value of a variable after variable has been changed

Tags: c

So I'm having a problem about showing what my original variable value is after changing it in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n, count =0;
    printf("enter an integer = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n!=0){
        n/=10;
        count++;
    }
    printf("your number %d has %d digits", n, count);
    return 0;
}
```

Example input:123
Output of this code "your number 0 has 3 digits"

I want to know how to be able to refer the variable "n" in the printf to the original value of '123' so the output will be "your number 123 has 3 digits"

Comment: Keep the original value in a second variable.

Comment: Hint: format your code properly, for example like the samples in your C text book.

Comment: Use another variable to save the value of `n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a separate variable to save your value or count with a different variable.

This code would look something like this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
   int n, count =0;
   printf("enter an integer = ");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   int buffer = n
   while (buffer!=0)
   {
     buffer/=10;
     count++;
   }
   printf("your number %d has %d digits", n, count);
   return 0;
 }
```

This way you save your variable in your code and you only used a buffer and not the actual value n.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a copy of the original variable and use that copy of the variable while printing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
int main(){
int n, count =0;
printf("enter an integer = ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("your number %d has ", n);
while (n!=0){
n/=10;
count++;
}
printf("%d digits", count);
return 0;
}
```

Of course, you may have to do some error checks..